# android studio dont show project folder structure

Tags: flutter, android-studio

android studio only show android folder but dont show other project folder structure (lib,ios,pubsec.yaml)

but these folders are exist in file explorer and app will run in VM

what is the issue?
[image]

Comment: on the top you need to click project view this is your android view

Answer (score 7):

1. Open Android Studio, and click **File > Project Structure**.
2. Redirect to **Project settings > Module**.
3. Select **yourProjectName_android** and **remove** it by clicking **(-)** minus sign shown on above.
4. Now click on **yourProjectName** and click on **+ Add Content Root** and just provide path of your project.
5. Just **Apply** and **Ok**.
6. **Restart** your android studio.

It's Done.

Happy Codding!!

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio (2021.2.1)

1. Click Android icon on left board
2. Change it from Android to Project

Check this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click Android Icon on left board and change Android to Project

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Click {project_name}_android module and click close icon blow that "Add Content Root" choose.

Click {project_name} module and click "Add Content Root" choose.

Answer (score 1):

you have opened the android project only you need to open the folder.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I open this (flutter root not android folder in flutter root project) but not show to me yet still. can you help me ?